# C# connecting to Firebird

Tags: c#, firebird

In most tutorials about connecting to Firebird from C#, they add several DLLs to the project. I downloaded the most recent ADO.NET driver and it included only one DLL file I have to reference to to get everything running. So I think these tutorials are just old and things have changed. Am I right, is it only one DLL I have to add? All works fine, but I don't want my application to give me an error at some point just because I overlooked something.

Comment: Why not to use Nuget?

Comment: If you ask such a question, you might want to consider including links to some of those tutorials. For all we know you are looking at tutorials about using Firebird Embedded from .NET, or using the native client implementation (both require additional DLLs in addition to the C# Firebird .NET provider).

Answer (score 1):

After installing Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider (4.1.0.0) package from NuGet I've got only one DLL in project output: *FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll*

So yes, only one DLL. Don't worry and use [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Firebird ADO.NET driver is a pure managed C# driver (it implements the Firebird network protocol) so yes you can use it with just one dll and it doesn't needs the fbclient.dll